# Return multiple tables in one SQL Connection using Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When i use Entity Framework Profiler the following code makes 3 calls to the database.

```
        using (var entities = new Entities())
        {
            var faqs = entities.Table1.ToList();
            var latest = entities.Table2.ToList();
            var inst = entities.Table3.ToList();

        }
```

I would like to make one database call, is there anyway to do this without calling a stored procedure?

I am trying to eliminate database calls throughout my application.

Comment: Create a view and import it.

Comment: I tried for a long time to get entity framework to support multiple result sets, in the end I failed. I instead used procedures and a simple result set transformer. You could look into Dapper (what StackExchange uses) as well.

Comment: Is there something specific that you are trying to grab out of those tables? Or are you just trying to grab everything?

Comment: In some MVC controllers i may grab some fields and in some i may grab all. My purpose is to eliminate calls to the database. So the tables may be unrelated.

Comment: So are you saying you want to only make 1 db call, store all those values in session, and then manipulate the data to fit your specific view's needs??

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i am saying.

Comment: The only thing I've found is a stored procedure....with select (all_columns) (but not using a *) from dbo.Table1, repeat for dbo.Table2 .. ("Note:EF does not take any mapping into account when it creates entities using the Translate method. It will simply match column names in the result set with property names on your classes.)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx

Comment: Look at this: https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/wiki/Future-Queries

Comment: Thanks i installed the NuGet Package for Entity Framework Extended. That is exactly what i needed. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a cross join in ef, 
See this
http://geekswithblogs.net/berthin/archive/2012/05/25/how-to-perform-cross-join.aspx

Comment: Fair enough, cross join is useful in case you have a few tables that you want to select some columns from in a single query to the database.

Answer (score -1):

My problem was solved by using the nuget package EntityFramework.Extended.

So using my original code, this is how you would solve my issue.

```
using (var entities = new Entities())
{
    var faqs = entities.Table1.Future();
    var latest = entities.Table2.Future();
    var inst = entities.Table3.Future();

    inst.ToList();
}
```

When you call ToList() a batch call is sent to your database in one connection.

The reference link is below:
https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/wiki/Future-Queries